# Zero-Copy messaging with zmqpp

Tags: zeromq

[ZeroCopy messaging](http://zeromq.org/blog:zero-copy) is something that can be implemented in zeromq, but is it possible to use it with the zmqpp c++ bindings? There is almost no documentation, and I was not able to find anything in the examples...

Comment: Which C++ binding are you using? cppzmq? In general, C++ should introduce few, if any, limitations from what you can achieve in straight C with ZMQ.  The key to acheiving zero copy in C appears to be the `zmq_msg_init_data` method, which appears to be loosely wrapped in the C++ bindings I've looked at, so it looks like you should find success by exploring that avenue.

Comment: I just saw you mentioned the zmqpp bindings specifically, let me see what I can see...

Comment: OK, I'm going to keep this in comments since I don't have a final answer to your question, but the only reference in your chosen binding to `zmq_msg_init_data` is in [frame.cpp](https://github.com/zeromq/zmqpp/blob/a590502f0119b15f880894a9421986c0a9c1b5cf/src/zmqpp/frame.cpp) - but a quick look through the codebase doesn't show anything initializing a frame with that signature, so it looks like you're going to have to do some manual building of message frames to do what you're after, but it should be possible.

Comment: Not the answer but if you are not too far into the project I would switch to cppzmq. It's a more active project and maintained by some of the core libzmq people. Its header only and has support for zero copy. https://github.com/zeromq/cppzmq

Comment: @JamesHarvey, yes, thanks, I don't like zmqpp so much. Very few documentation, it doesn't seem to be well maintained... I don't understand why there are two different c++ bindings in the zeromq project page on github anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would switch to [cppzmq](https://github.com/zeromq/cppzmq).

It's a more active project and maintained by some of the core libzmq people.

It's header only and has support for zero copy.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply use zmqpp::message::copy().

In the zmqpp [source code](https://github.com/zeromq/zmqpp/blob/develop/src/zmqpp/message.cpp) we can see:

```
void message::copy(message const& source)
{
    _parts.resize( source._parts.size() );
    for(size_t i = 0; i < source._parts.size(); ++i)
    {
        _parts[i] = source._parts[i].copy();
    }

    // we don't need a copy of the releasers as we did data copies of the internal data,
    //_releasers = source._releasers;
    //_strings = source._strings
}
```

the _parts which defined as:

```
private:
    typedef std::vector<frame> parts_type;
    parts_type _parts;
```

so, source._parts[i].copy() actually call zmqpp::frame::copy() which defined [here](https://github.com/zeromq/zmqpp/blob/develop/src/zmqpp/frame.cpp):

```
frame frame::copy() const
{
    frame other( size() );
    other._sent = _sent;

    if( 0 != zmq_msg_copy( &other._msg, const_cast<zmq_msg_t*>(&_msg) ) )
    {
        throw zmq_internal_exception();
    }

    return other;
}
```

zmqpp::frame::_msg in the code snippet is defined as zmq_msg_t. All zmq_msg_t object in the frame objects of source zmqpp::message object been zero copied by zmq_msg_copy to new zmqpp::message object.

so, zmqpp::message::copy() help us get a new zmqpp::message object which it's all frame is zero copied from the source zmqpp::message object.